# Understanding React Code

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-component, react-router-component

I am learning React.js. I am familiar with below code

```
class Login extends Component {
    state = { email: '',};
    render = () => {
        return (//some JSX code);
    }
}
```

But I got below code as solution of an issue.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
        render={props =>
            (Auth.isAuthenticated() ? ( <Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/',}}/>))
      }
    />
);
```

I could not understand above code. Could anyone help me to understand ?

What is `{...rest}` here?

I know spread operator. Why I am passing it here `({ component: Component, ...rest })` and here  `<Route {...rest}` ? What is it doing in this two places ?

Why the `render()` is look like this `render={props => }` ?

Thanks all.

Comment: `{...rest}` is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). When you write `render={props => ... }` you are giving a function to the `render` prop. It might look more obvious at first if you write `render={(props) => { return ... }}`

Answer (score 1):

{...rest} is a destructuration of an object ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
In react you can write component as extension of Component class (managed component) or as extension of PureComponent or Functional Component (unmanaged component). 
The one you are asking for is a Functional Component. 
Destructuring is an ES6 feature, while components are react's feature and you can find all info and patterns in react official doc.

Comment: Thanks @Mose Raguzzini. I would like to know more about Functional Component. Could you please help me in this regard ?

Comment: Here we go: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html . React's documentation is really well made :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question - it is the [Object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), citing [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object
>   expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs
>   (for object literals) are expected.

In your case, what it does is the `PrivateRoute` component passes all the props (except for `component`) as props to the `Route` component.

Regarding the second question - this is basically the [render props pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) for explanation, as it's quite long. But basically what happens is that the `Route` component takes a function as its `render` prop, and that function's responsibility is to render some content based on the `props` passed to it.